# printing the summary of glm

Tags: r, printing

I am struggling with saving/printing the glm model summary output. Here is my code;

```
logmodel=glm(amal~age + LC1 + LC2 + LC3 + LC4, data=random_new, family="binomial")
summary(logmodel)
```

And output is ;

```
Call:
glm(formula = amal ~ age + LC1 + LC2 + LC3 + LC4, family = "binomial", 
data = random100_new)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-1.17907  -0.59278  -0.00008  -0.00008   2.37302  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -2.336e-03  1.155e-01  -0.020    0.984    
age          2.633e-05  9.838e-04   0.027    0.979    
LC11        -1.957e+01  4.065e+02  -0.048    0.962    
LC21        -2.752e+00  1.762e-01 -15.617   <2e-16 ***
LC31        -1.957e+01  4.065e+02  -0.048    0.962    
LC41        -1.648e+00  1.275e-01 -12.918   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 2888.7  on 3499  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1907.0  on 3494  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1919

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 18
```

I did try;
    `result=summary.glm(logmodel)$coefficients
        write.csv(result, file="x.csv")`

But it just save the coefficients of the model. Is there any way to save all summary output?

Thanks.

Comment: Both sink and capture output have many prior answers that illustrate their use.

Comment: I am a new R user like 2 months. I didn't know there is a function sink or capture output. Before I asked the question I did research in this site, but couldn't find an answer.Anyways, thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use

```
sink("outfile.txt")  ## switch standard output to a file
summary(logmodel)
sink()               ## don't forget to turn off redirection
                     ## lots of scope for confusion here!
```

`capture.output` may be safer/recommended because you run less risk of forgetting to un-redirect ...

```
writeLines(capture.output(summary(logmodel)),con="outfile.txt")
```

Sending the output to a CSV file doesn't really make any sense ...

Comment: +1 for `capture.output`

Comment: thanks a lot Ben. writeLines function works perfect for me.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't make sense to save the entire output of a model as a CSV because summary output is not a table. If you want to save the full output you are essentially saving a list (not a table/csv). You can just do:

```
x<-summary(yourmodel)
save(x, file="modelresults.Rdata")
```

Comment: True, and useful, but not I think what the OP wants -- I think they actually want to save the printed representation ...

Comment: Yeap, I did try save("Rda") function. It didnt work, because I want to save it to print.